# Which WebView2 event/function can be use to replace ScriptNotify Webview event?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, webview2

Today, I have decided to migrate `WebView` control to `WebView2` control in a VB.net application.

I have installed `WebView2` from `NuGet` and I have changed declarations and initialization lines (only 4 lines in my VB program because I'm using 2 WebView2).

When I build my application, `Visual Studio 2019` indicates that `ScriptNotify` event is not an event of `WebView2`!

```
Private Sub wvSelect_ScriptNotify(
    sender As Object, 
    e As WebViewControlScriptNotifyEventArgs) Handles wvSelect.ScriptNotify
```

Using old `WebView` control, this event is generated using `windows.external.notify` Javascript function.

```
function clickPlus(e) { window.external.notify("+PLUS:"); }
```

Which event is replacing `ScriptNotify` event in `WebView2` control?

I'm interested to know the new event and also how this event is called from Javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few possible scenarios to handle event notifications with [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/):
See also: [Use JavaScript in WebView for extended scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/how-to/javascript).

Generic initialization:

- The WebView2 instance is named `myWebView2`.
- Using basic methods: for example, the JSON deserialization is performed using JavaScriptSerializer. You probably have Json.Net or System.Text.Json instead.
- Also assuming WinForms, you haven't specified the GUI framework

```
Private Async Sub Load(sender As Object, e as EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    await myWebView2.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(Nothing)
End Sub
```

Also, I'm using this simple class model, used to deserialize the JSON message received, since [WebView2.WebMessageReceived](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.winforms.webview2.webmessagereceived) assumes a JSON format; you can pass whatever string you want, though.

```
Private Class JsonEventMessage
    Public Property Element As String
    Public Property Value As String
End Class
```

---

**1 -** In this scenario, javascript Functions are already defined in the HTML

- Using `JSON.stringify()` to emphasize that the return value is a JSON object

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function SomeFunction(e, v) {
           var json = JSON.stringify({ Element:e.target.id, Value:v });
           window.chrome.webview.postMessage(json);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("div1").addEventListener("click", function(e) {SomeFunction(e, '+PLUS:')});
    </script>
    <div id="div1">Some Text to Click</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In this case, you just need to subscribe to the `WebMessageReceived` event and deserialize the JSON:

```
AddHandler myWebView2.WebMessageReceived, AddressOf myWebView2_WebMessageReceived

' [...]

Private Sub myWebView2_WebMessageReceived(sender As Object, e As CoreWebView2WebMessageReceivedEventArgs)
    Dim message = New JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of JsonEventMessage)(e.TryGetWebMessageAsString())
    Console.WriteLine(message.Element)
    Console.WriteLine(message.Value)
End Sub
```

Note: I'm using [e.TryGetWebMessageAsString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2webmessagereceivedeventargs.trygetwebmessageasstring) and not [e.WebMessageAsJson](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2webmessagereceivedeventargs.webmessageasjson) since the latter is enclosed in quotes (*double-stringified*). It's better used when you pass a simple string.

---

**2 -** Here, a JavaScript Function that can notify a message is defined in `HEAD`, but no event handlers are added anywhere else.
Assume you will add HTML Elements at run-time or you don't want to add the event handlers in the HTML or anything else.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function SomeFunction(e, v) {
           var json = JSON.stringify({ Element:e.target.id, Value:v });
           window.chrome.webview.postMessage(json);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1">Some Text to Click</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Subscribe to the `WebMessageReceived` event as before and to the [NavigationCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.winforms.webview2.navigationcompleted) event. This event is raised when the Document is loaded. We need this event, since, in the example, the event handlers are added to Elements in the Body, which is not available before this point.

In `NavigationCompleted`, we can add the JavaScript Function to a string and call the [WebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.winforms.webview2.executescriptasync) method, which executes the script after the DOM is ready, otherwise `GetElementById()` would not find the target.

```
AddHandler myWebView2.WebMessageReceived, AddressOf myWebView2_WebMessageReceived
AddHandler myWebView2.NavigationCompleted, AddressOf myWebView2_NavigationCompleted

' [...]

Private Sub myWebView2_WebMessageReceived(sender As Object, e As CoreWebView2WebMessageReceivedEventArgs)
    Dim message = New JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of JsonEventMessage)(e.TryGetWebMessageAsString())
    ' [...]
End Sub

Private Async Sub myWebView2_NavigationCompleted(sender As Object, e As CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs)
    Dim func As String =
        "document.getElementById('div1').
            addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
                SomeFunction(e, '+PLUS:')
            });"
    Await myWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync(func)
End Sub
```

---

**3 -** This time, no JavaScript Functions are defined anywhere in the HTML.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1">Some Text to Click</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Case 1:**
Subscribe to the `WebMessageReceived` and `NavigationCompleted` events as before.

In `NavigationCompleted`, the JavaScript Function that posts the message is added to the event handler directly. Call `ExecuteScriptAsync()` to execute the script and add the Event Listener to a HTML Element.

```
AddHandler myWebView2.WebMessageReceived, AddressOf myWebView2_WebMessageReceived
AddHandler myWebView2.NavigationCompleted, AddressOf myWebView2_NavigationCompleted

' [...]

Private Sub myWebView2_WebMessageReceived(sender As Object, e As CoreWebView2WebMessageReceivedEventArgs)
    Dim message = New JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of JsonEventMessage)(e.TryGetWebMessageAsString())
    ' [...]
End Sub

Private Async Sub myWebView2_NavigationCompleted(sender As Object, e As CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs)
    Dim func As String =
    "document.getElementById('div1').
        addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
            var json = JSON.stringify({Element:e.target.id, Value:'+PLUS:'});
            window.chrome.webview.postMessage(json); 
    });"
    Await myWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync(func)
End Sub
```

**Case 2**:
Subscribe to the `WebMessageReceived` and [WebView2.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.winforms.webview2.corewebview2initializationcompleted).
In this case, we're adding an event listener to the Document, then determine which Element has been clicked using the `Event.Target` member and any other  property or value that can be useful to handle the notification.

Here, I'm simply passing the `[Event].target.id` and `[Event].target.innerText` as JSON properties. You can of course get any other attribute necessary in your use-case.

```
AddHandler myWebView2.WebMessageReceived, AddressOf myWebView2_WebMessageReceived
AddHandler myWebView2.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted, AddressOf myWebView2_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted
' [...]

Private Sub myWebView2_WebMessageReceived(sender As Object, e As CoreWebView2WebMessageReceivedEventArgs)
    Dim message = New JavaScriptSerializer().
        Deserialize(Of JsonEventMessage)(e.TryGetWebMessageAsString())
    ' [...]
End Sub

Private Async Sub myWebView2_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(
    sender As Object, 
    e As CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs)

    Dim func as String = 
    "document.addEventListener
        ('click', function(e) {
            window.chrome.webview.postMessage(
                JSON.stringify({ Element:e.target.id, Value:e.target.innerText })
            );
       });"
    Await myWebView2.CoreWebView2.AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync(func)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem is now solved and my solution is following ...

I want to display following HTML page

```
<div id="table">
    <div id='Keyboard' class='panel'>
        <div class='krow'>
            <span class='k digit'>7</span>
            <span class='k digit'>8</span>
            <span class='k digit'>9</span>
            <span class='k back'>&#x2B60;x</span>
        </div>
        <div class='krow'>
            <span class='k digit'>4</span>
            <span class='k digit'>5</span>
            <span class='k digit'>6</span>
            <span class='k delete'>x&#x2B60;</span>
        </div>
        <div class='krow'>
            <span class='k digit'>1</span>
            <span class='k digit'>2</span>
            <span class='k digit'>3</span>
            <span class='k clear'>&#x21E4;&#x22C6;</span>
        </div>
        <div class='krow'>
            <span class='k empty'></span>
            <span class='k digit'>0</span>
            <span class='k point'>.</span>
            <span class='k plus'><b>+</b></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To intercept `click` on digit <div>, I have written following Javascript lines

```
$(document).ready(function ()
    {
    $('.digit').click(function (ev) { clickDigit(ev); });
    ...
    }

function clickDigit(e)
    {
    eDigit = e.target;
    var sValue = eDigit.innerText;
    window.chrome.webview.postMessage("+DIGIT:" + sValue);
    }
```

As you can see, I call `postMessage()` function to send a notification to VB.Net code.

To initiaze and display my HTML code, I have written following lines

```
Private Sub Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    InitializeAsync()
End Sub

Async Sub InitializeAsync()
    Await wvSelect.EnsureCoreWebView2Async()
    wvSelect.NavigateToString(sHtmlText)
End Sub
```

where `WebView2` control is defined in Designer part of my Form

```
Friend WithEvents wvSelect As Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2
```

Finally, to intercept JavaScript notification, I have written following VB.Net Code

```
Private Sub wvSelect_WebMessageReceived(sender As Object, e As CoreWebView2WebMessageReceivedEventArgs) _
    Handles wvSelect.WebMessageReceived

    Dim sValue As String = e.TryGetWebMessageAsString
    Dim iPos = sValue.IndexOf(":")
    Dim sAction = sValue.Substring(0, iPos)
    sValue = sValue.Substring(iPos + 1)

    Select Case sAction
        Case "+DIGIT"
            SendMessage(txtInput.Handle, WM_CHAR, AscW(sValue.Chars(0)), 0)
```

I hope than what I have reported in this answer can help others users and complete `Jimi` answer.