# Embedding Youtube Videos in c# WinForms and DetectingWhen The Video Is Over

Tags: c#, winforms, iframe, youtube, embed

I am trying to code a very simple youtube player in C#. My specifications are as follows:

1. Passing in a playlist id and getting a list of videos
2. Creating a button control for each of these videos with a double click event to play that video
3. Displaying these buttons inside a scrollable panel
4. Detecting when one video ends and automatically playing the next one

[UI and stuff is still very much work in progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHTHA.png)

So far I have created a WebBrowser control and I can set it's DocumentText to

```
<html><head><meta content='IE=Edge' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'/><iframe id='video' src= 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/{0}?autoplay=1' width='600' height='300' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>
```

The {0} I am simply replacing with the video id.

I am using the `Google.Apis.YouTube.v3` library to get the videos from the playlist, and I am creating buttons for each of them on my main form. I can use these buttons to play different videos, the only part I can't figure out is how to detect a video ending so I can autoplay the next one.

I have thought of maybe embedding the playlist itself but I don't know how that would work and I would like to keep my buttons for selecting which song to play.

So what is the best way to embed youtube videos and detect when they're over?

Comment: HTML5 has standard events to represent states of a `video` element. You can attach an event listener (`addEventListener()`) to the `ended` event. See the events summary here: [HTML Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html). You should probably plan on replacing the WebBrowser Control with [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winforms).

Comment: The question is, how would I get the event to trigger my c# code. Does the webbrowser/WebView2 expose events from the embedded content or something?

Comment: Here: [Which WebView2 event/function can be use to replace ScriptNotify Webview event?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68278278/7444103) are described 3 different scenarios, to get standard or custom notifications when an event is triggered by a HTML element. Either when the functionality is embedded in the HTML or when you need to inject a function, an event or both in the DOM from your code, because no such functionality is present in the HTML. -- It's written in VB.Net, for WebView2, but it's almost identical to C# code.