# Binding Webview2 to HTML document

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, webview2

In my application, where I read a pdf from SQL, I use the `.NavigateToString` method to view it  embedded into a html document via the `webview2` control.

Currently, I am reading the data from SQL and load it manually with `.NavigateToString` (thx to @Jimi).

It would be great to bind the database field directly to the control. But the only useful bindable property I found was the `source` property which needs an url.

Is there a way to achieve this aproach ?

Comment: You can theoretically setup a .Net class object and *bind* it to a JavaScript function using the [AddHostObjectToScript()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.addhostobjecttoscript) method of CoreWebView2 (the JavaScript can change the `src` Attribute of an IFrame element with the data received) and *bind* Html elements to .Net class methods/events using a JavaScript function that posts back calling `window.chrome.webview.postMessage()` (I've described this procedure [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68278278/7444103)).

Comment: You can then use standard data bindings to bind a `BindingList<Class>` (where the `Class` object implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` or standard Property/PropertyChanged event coupling) to the HTML using these methods., creating a sort of two-way binding. -- This implies that you need to load all the data in memory or, if not feasible, use a form of pagination (a DataGridView in VirtualMode can help with that).

Comment: Thx so much for your help, but after following your advice and trying to get into the topic more deeper, I decided, the effort is not worth it. Reading the binary manually from DB and framing some HTML around does the work pretty well. It was just about looking for an optimal implementation,

Answer (score 1):

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b1e89c65-e95d-49a3-a221-cae46cfd1c6e/uwpchow-to-binding-string-html-to-webview-in-listviewitemtemplate?forum=wpdevelop

C#

```
public class Untils
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceStringProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SourceString", typeof(string), typeof(Untils), new PropertyMetadata("", OnSourceStringChanged));

    public static string GetSourceString(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return obj.GetValue(SourceStringProperty).ToString();
    }

    public static void SetSourceString(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(SourceStringProperty, value);
    }

    private static async void OnSourceStringChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebView2 wv = d as WebView2;
        await wv.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
        if (wv != null)
        {
            wv.NavigateToString(e.NewValue.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

WPF

add
<Window

...

xmlns:wv2="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf;assembly=Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf">

<wv2:WebView2  Name="webViewPdf" local:Untils.SourceString="{Binding Path=message.desc}"/>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).