# How to parse text with WebView2 control

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, parsing, webview2

I need to get the text that constantly changing from a website that does not load with the old Web Browser control, so I'm moving for the first time steps on WebView2

The html I want to parse is:

```
<td data-v-39c7db2a="" class="text-right">
0.0000%
</td>
```

the value I need is the percentage.
The code I'm using is

```
Private Sub WebView2_NavigationCompleted(sender As Object, e As CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebView2.NavigationCompleted

Dim text As String = Await WebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('text-right').selectedIndex")
MessageBox.Show(text)
```

It doesn just return a messagebox with "null"
It's kind of complicated now to move from the old webbrowser control to the WebView, also because of the lack of documentation.

Comment: `text-right` is not the `ID`, it's the `class` name, which is an `Attribute` of the HtmlElement. So, you have an element with a specific `TAG` name and a `ClassName` that might not be specific. Some form of parsing is probably needed. Also, handling `NavigationCompleted` will get you just the initial value, not value changes over time.

Comment: Hey Jimi, such a pleasure to hear from you again. 
You are obv right, I've tried with `("Document.All('text-right').GetAttribute('value')")` still getting the null.
I will probably use a timer for that,  still need to digest webview2 control

Comment: As mentioned, `text-righ` is the `ClassName`, not the `ID`, not the `Name`. Have you tried `document.getElementsByClassName()`? See also the methods described here: [Which WebView2 event/function can be use to replace ScriptNotify Webview event?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68278278/7444103), to inject scripts and event listeners, since you probably need to receive events when the value changes.

Comment: Is the `data-v-39c7db2a=""` unique to the element you want?

Comment: @Jimi it gives me this weird messagebox [link](https://imgur.com/a/d9chRUt)
That would cost me a brain freeze to understand :D... I would be happy if I can make it works with a simple parsing. I'm trying to create an alert for a broker website which doesn't have notification either on the phone app. So I'm just thinking to do a little utility that check the percentuage of the order, if filled or not.

Comment: @jimi Also, I just sow that placing another order, it would be created with the same html `data-v-39c7db2a=""` ecc, so i might create a loop to get % from all orders, but to make it easy now,  I'll just place a single order to I just need to parse 1 single %. Thanks :)

Comment: @jimi [link](https://imgur.com/nnEq5AW) this is the entire html

Comment: @Jimi  & PoulBak [link](https://imgur.com/3gflOjq) this is instead a video example of how the html is identical for each order placed

Comment: I won't be on Windows until the half of next month, I cannot make tests using WebView2 and, more importantly, we don't have the real html page, to verify how it actually behaves. -- The code you posted is awaiting a method in a non-`async` proc, so it's probably not your real code. Post what you have, including other attempts based on the suggestions -- Work with @Poul Bak, he knows this stuff.

Comment: I'm using the code under a button and that's the only code I'm using since it's a clean new project, the other suggestions unfortunately will return me the same "null" still using them under a simple button.
I wish you good holidays and a great new year Jimi san.

Comment: The website has an API that you can query to get the data without using a browser. That would make it much easier to work with ;)

Comment: Hi, unfortunately HotBit doesn't have official API i can use to make everything easier..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really associated with `WebView2` but a pure javascript problem.

You need to use:

```
document.querySelector('td.text-right').textContent
```

This returns the text for the first table cell with class name 'text-right'.

However this might not work for you if there's more than one table cell with the class name `text-right'.

In that case you can query for the nth child, where `n` is the child index:

```
document.querySelector('td.text-right:nth-child(7)').textContent
```

To get the percentage value as a `Double`:

```
Dim percent as Double = Double.Parse(Regex.Match(text, "[\d.]+").ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I've tried all of yours updates but all they return "null" on the messagebox. To clarify, I've posted the screenshot under @Jimi comment.

Comment: The software is open probably 10 minutes but it still return me null...

Comment: Oops, my mistake, `querySelector` should be camel case! Try it now.

Comment: Thanks Poul, we almost there [link](https://imgur.com/hygDhGE)

Comment: That's great Poul thanks. Just a consideration. I've tried to change the n 7 with 6 or 8 in order to get the percentage of a second order, but with 6 it gives me null, with 8 it gives me "Cancel" in the msgbox.. Which n should I use in order to get a second percentage?

Comment: If you want to get more than one value, it's more complicated. I suggest you ask a new question (and please include the code/html in your question, images are bad - we can't copy from them).

Comment: Do you think it might work in a for loop?
If not, I will ask another question and I'll insert the full html.

by the way, the regex gives me an error "Value of type 'Match' cannot be converted to 'String'."

Comment: Added .ToString()`` to the match (Parse works with strings)

Comment: Thanks, that resolve the error. But trying with 40.0000% it return 400000, it might need some formatting? Also, I take the advantage to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70545073/how-to-parse-values-in-a-table-cell-with-the-same-class-name) you the new question. I appreciate your help, Poul.
edit: without any order placed, so with the table empty, your code gives me still a value : 1000000

Comment: Your computer probably uses comma as decimalseparator, so I add `CultureInfo InvariantCulture`. That should fix the problem (using `.`)

Comment: Endeed it fix the problem, but it's quite weird how it still gives me 100 even if the table is empty :\.. that would trick the software since I don't know if the order will be empty or already filled since both returns 100

Comment: I got the impression ExecuteScriptAsync kind of make a mess since sometimes after I use it, the software is being closed.. 
Your code  returns "100" if values in table cells are empty but also adding and removing seems bugged since It seems values are "stored" even after I delete the order.  I made a gif to make it clear. [link](https://imgur.com/6zWrWts)
Thanks and I wish you bests of holidays