# How to parse values in a table cell with the same class name

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, parsing, webview2

I am trying to get the values in a table cell with the same class name through the control WebView2

[This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70543596/2497570)

it's useful to get a single value, but now I want to take in consideration that can happen to have more than a single value.
The table full html code is:

```
<tbody data-v-39c7db2a=""><tr data-v-39c7db2a=""><td data-v-39c7db2a="" class="text-left">12-31 19:57:47</td> <td data-v-39c7db2a="" class="text-center">Limit</td> <td data-v-39c7db2a="" class="text-center market">KIBA/USDT</td> <td data-v-39c7db2a="" class="text-left price price-down">
                                0.00003888
                            </td> <td data-v-39c7db2a="" class="amount leftAmount text-left"><span data-v-39c7db2a=""><!---->
                                    100
                                    KIBA
                                </span></td> <td data-v-39c7db2a="" class="text-left total">
                                0.00388800
                                
                                USDT
                            </td> <td data-v-39c7db2a="" class="text-right">
                                0.0000%
                            </td> <td data-v-39c7db2a="" class="text-right"><span data-v-39c7db2a="" class="cancel ordersO_title_cancelall">Cancel</span></td></tr><tr data-v-39c7db2a=""><td data-v-39c7db2a="" class="text-left">12-31 19:43:51</td> <td data-v-39c7db2a="" class="text-center">Limit</td> <td data-v-39c7db2a="" class="text-center market">KIBA/USDT</td> <td data-v-39c7db2a="" class="text-left price price-down">
                                0.00003890
                            </td> <td data-v-39c7db2a="" class="amount leftAmount text-left"><span data-v-39c7db2a=""><!---->
                                    100
                                    KIBA
                                </span></td> <td data-v-39c7db2a="" class="text-left total">
                                0.00389000
                                
                                USDT
                            </td> <td data-v-39c7db2a="" class="text-right">
                                0.0000%
                            </td> <td data-v-39c7db2a="" class="text-right"><span data-v-39c7db2a="" class="cancel ordersO_title_cancelall">Cancel</span></td></tr></tbody>
```

while the code of each row in the table is:

```
<tr data-v-39c7db2a=""><td data-v-39c7db2a="" class="text-left">12-31 19:57:47</td> <td data-v-39c7db2a="" class="text-center">Limit</td> <td data-v-39c7db2a="" class="text-center market">KIBA/USDT</td> <td data-v-39c7db2a="" class="text-left price price-down">
                                0.00003888
                            </td> <td data-v-39c7db2a="" class="amount leftAmount text-left"><span data-v-39c7db2a=""><!---->
                                    100
                                    KIBA
                                </span></td> <td data-v-39c7db2a="" class="text-left total">
                                0.00388800
                                
                                USDT
                            </td> <td data-v-39c7db2a="" class="text-right">
                                0.0000%
                            </td> <td data-v-39c7db2a="" class="text-right"><span data-v-39c7db2a="" class="cancel ordersO_title_cancelall">Cancel</span></td></tr>
```

The values I'm interested are the percentage like in this case 0.0000%.
Since the class names are the same, how can I loop in order to get all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires some more javascript to work. However, once implemented it should work better.
First save the following javascript to '**script.js**' in your project's root directory (or a subdirectory, if you change the path in code). **Make sure you select the file's properties and select `Copy to output directory: Copy if newer`**. That copies the script file so `WebView2` can find it.

Here's the javascript:

```
let GetOrders = function ()
{
    let doubles = [];
    let cells = document.querySelectorAll('div.ordersO.exchange-card.layout-r  td.text-right');
    let filteredArray = Array.from(cells).filter(function (value)
    {
        return value.textContent.includes('%') && value.nextElementSibling?.firstElementChild?.textContent.includes('Cancel');
    });
    filteredArray.forEach(function (value)
    {
        doubles.push(+/[\d.+-]+/.exec(value.textContent)[0]);
    });
    return doubles;
};
```

Now that you have the javascript, you can implement the code in your form. Since I don't know Vb.net, I show the code in C# (should be easy to translate). Here's the entire form file:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core;

namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await webView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
            //webView21.CoreWebView2.Navigate(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "html.html")); // Just my testing with your html
        }

        private async void WebView21_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            string script = File.ReadAllText("script.js");
            await webView21.CoreWebView2.AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync(script);
        }

        private async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string json = await webView21.ExecuteScriptAsync("GetOrders()");
            decimal[] orders = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<decimal[]>(json) ?? Array.Empty<decimal>();

            if (orders.Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No orders");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(String.Join(',', orders));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I use `CoreWebView2.AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync` - that injects the code in the page, so you can call it later.

Since `ExecuteScriptAsync` returns JSON, I use `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<decimal[]>` to create an array of `decimal` values.

This code will also work if there are no orders (returns an empty array).

**Edit**:

Changed to use `Newtonsoft.Json`.

**Edit2**:

Changed the javascript code to avoid duplicates!

Comment: Hey Poul thanks a lot for take part of your time to help me on this. So, since it's something above my skills, I'm trying slowly to implement what you saying. I converted all the code from c# to vb.net but it gives me an error "Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'JsonReader'. on `Dim orders As Decimal() = If(JsonSerializer.Deserialize(Of Decimal())(json), Array.Empty(Of Decimal)())` more precisely on (json) .. might it be a translator mistake?

Comment: Have you added: `using System.Text.Json;`? You might be using a different `JsonSerializer`, which uses a different syntax (for instance 'Json.Net' - in that case try `JsonConvert.Deserialize`).

Comment: I was using newtonsoft.json, now I just installed Json.net and modified the code in `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`, but having 2 orders opened, it gives me "no orders" [link](https://imgur.com/2Dc0Yf8) to make it clear, the new code is under button2. Button1 contain the previous question code.

Comment: Hey Poul, I copied the html exactly from the page. Yeah the table cell contain a number follow by % just like this "100.0000%", this is the [link](https://imgur.com/Sb31sDC) where script.js is located, hope its right.

Comment: I changed the code to use `Newtonsoft.Json` - this works fine for me ('Json.net' might not support my code).

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't change the problem. I just downloaded the html page and made this gif to make it clear on what I'm doing( still thanks for your help). GIF  [link](https://imgur.com/a/xq5SYeA) , HTML page [link](https://ufile.io/sh17hne3) (literally didn't know where to upload it)
p.s. just a noob question: would it be possible to use the code you gave me in the previous question ( that works for a single order only) and make a for loop in order to get all the percentages?  Thanks :)

Comment: Just tried your new html, get a big list! Try putting breakpoints in your code. Does `WebView21_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted`even run, also check the value of `json`, is it null, empty? And the previous question's answer will always return the same number (the first). This should give you ALL.

Comment: What you mean with "get a big list"? In that html there is just one open order, do not consider the 24 h order history.. Did it work to you? 
To me : probably it doesnt run `WebView21_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted` cause at debugging it doesnt even trigger the breakpoints. I think its one of my mistakes copying the script.. If it don't bother you, I've just uploaded the project in a rar [link](https://ufile.io/zyz8mrdx) , thanks

Comment: Ah, if the code doesn't run, then I understand. Open the form designer, click `WebView2`, in Properties Window, click events button, find `CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted`, click the dropdown and select `WebView21_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted`. Also check that `Form1_Load` runs.

Comment: ook now we went through the next step, it s considering the script but it returns lots of differents values, gif [link](https://imgur.com/9npfQi9)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240644/discussion-between-poul-bak-and-mattia).