# WebView2 on remote computer

Tags: wpf, vb.net, webview2

I have a problem with webview2. I have WPF/vb.net app
First I can't make auto log in to the page.
Second, I tested it on remote computer and it doesn't work. It doesn't give errors, just empty field.
I appreciate any help
p.s.WebView2 Runtime is installed on both computers

```
front:

<wv2:WebView2 Name="webView2 " Source="pageName" CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted="zzz_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted">
</wv2:WebView2>


back:

webView2 .EnsureCoreWebView2Async()


Private Sub webView2 _CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(sender As Object, e As Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs)
        Dim userName ="user"
        Dim password = "password"       webView2.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById(""signin_username"").InnerText='" & userName & "';")


p.s. for front I just deleted source and at the back I didn't wrote here the code for password and button, I think I will manage to do it if you can help me with just username.
```

Comment: See here: [Which WebView2 event/function can be use to replace ScriptNotify Webview event?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68278278/7444103), the last two snippets, more precisely -- No Document is yet loaded in `CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted`, that event is about the initialization of the Component, not the Document(s) / Frames

Comment: Also, `.InnerText` should be `.innerText`. You should use the Edge browser navigated to the page you want to modify and open DevTools and use the console to try out running the script you intend to inject with WebView2 to make sure the script will work the way you want.