# Vb.net - capturing click event in webview2 control

Tags: javascript, vb.net, webview2

I'm trying to capture a click event in a webview2 control and I can't seem to get it to function.

Webview2 is initialised and renders the HTML as desired, and I've added a handler for webmessage received...

```
 AddHandler Webview2.WebMessageReceived, AddressOf Webview2_WebMessageReceived
```

This is just attempting to throw a messagebox for now...

```
Private Async Sub Webview2_WebMessageReceived(sender As Object, e As CoreWebView2WebMessageReceivedEventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show(e.TryGetWebMessageAsString)
End Sub
```

Within the HTML being rendered i've got a button with id="butt1".

In the webview2's navigation completed event, I'm firing this to listen for the click...

```
 Await Webview2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementsById('butt1').click();")
```

Everything runs without exception, yet the messagebox is never fired on button click.

Can anyone nudge me in the right direction here?

Comment: See the different examples / methods here: [Which WebView2 event/function can be use to replace ScriptNotify Webview event?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68278278/7444103)

Comment: Please also share the JavaScript you have that is trying to raise the WebMessageReceived event. I would guess the id='butt1' button will run script that is calling chrome.webview.postMessage ? Also, have you tried opening the DevTools in WebView2, (right click, Inspect) and look for any errors or exceptions in the console?